How can I create transparent buttons that react to touches but pass drag gestures to the views below?
I have a fulscreen SpriteKit scene view, that handles pan gestures within itself.
Over it, I have overlaid native SwiftUI views with OnTapGesture, which must react to them being touched but should not interfere with pan gestures, and pass them below.
.allowHitTesting(false) completely removes any reaction to touches, pan gestures work but button handlers won't.
I've written a small example that recreates my situation:
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            Rectangle() //simulates spriteKit view
                .fill(.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged(
                    { value in
                        //simulates spriteKit drag handling,
                        //for example animated page flipping
                        print("DragGesture",value.velocity)
                    } ))
                
            HStack(spacing: 0) //my buttons
            {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red.opacity(0.00001))
                    .border(.red, width: 2)
                    .onTapGesture
                    {
                        // this one gets called,
                        // but sk drag gesture is NOT called
                        print("flip page left")
                    }
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.clear)
                    .border(.green, width: 2)
                    .onTapGesture
                    {
                        // this one is NOT called,
                        // and sk gesture is called
                        print("flip page right")
                    }
                
                Button(action:
                        {
                            // this one gets called,
                            // but sk drag gesture is NOT called
                            print("button PRESSED")
                        },
                       label:
                        {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(.black)
                                .border(.yellow, width: 2)
                        })
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    TestView()
}


So, to reiterate: How can I make TRANSPARENT (or 0.0001 opacity) overlaying buttons that capture single touches but can pass pan (or drag) gestures to the views below them?

In my experience, it's best to define the gestures separately and then use them as needed. This will offer more flexibility for using them with composing gestures modifiers  like .simultaneously, .exclusively and .sequenced, but also with GestureMask parameters.
Here's the revised code for you to try:
import SwiftUI

struct DragTapTestView: View {
    
    //Gestures
    let dragGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3)
        .onChanged { value in
            //simulates spriteKit drag handling,
            //for example animated page flipping
            print("DragGesture",value.velocity)
        }
    
    let flipLeftTap =  TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            print("flip page left")
        }
    
    let flipRightTap =  TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            print("flip page right")
        }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            //Background with drag gesture
            Rectangle() //simulates spriteKit view
                .fill(.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .gesture(dragGesture)
            
            //Buttons
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                //Flip Left
                Color.clear
                    .border(.red, width: 2)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .gesture(
                        flipLeftTap
                            .simultaneously(with: dragGesture) //Note this could trigger both a drag and a tap, depending on drag distance and timing
                    )
                
                //Spacer
                Color.clear
                    .border(.green, width: 2)
                
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    //Flip Right
                    Color.clear
                        .border(.yellow, width: 2)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(
                            dragGesture
                                .exclusively(before: flipRightTap) //more reliable - compare this with the left tap approach
                        )
                    
                    //Flip Right - Alternate method using a button
                    Button {
                        print("flip right button PRESSED")
                    } label: {
                        Color.clear
                            .border(.orange, width: 2)
                    }
                    .highPriorityGesture(dragGesture, including: .gesture) //Button already has a native tap gesture
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DragTapTestView()
}

Note that there are two methods for flipping right - one using a Button, one without.
More importantly, pay attention to the difference between the left and right methods as you test. Try dragging on the left area multiple times and you may notice that sometimes it can trigger both a drag and a tap at the same time. This may result in a double page flip, depending on your implementation.
Compare the dragging on the left area with the dragging on any of the right areas, which should not trigger both a drag and a tap.

Thank you for your fast reply!
As good and clear as it is - it does not help me, because gesture system of underlying view is done separately and is not available for me to compose with native SwiftUI gestures.
They're made via SKScene didMove override and UIPanGestureRecognizer (or tap or pinch variants), that are linked to view via UIView addGestureRecognizer, so i'm stuck again.

That should have been part of the "brief" and /or mentioned in the code comments. Or, at least put everything that simulates the underlying view into a struct so it's self contained and mention no changes should be done to it.

If the drag gesture doesn't have to be attached to the blue rectangle in the background, then it works to move the drag gesture to the HStack containing the buttons. Also, if you want the middle button to react to tap gestures too, you can add a .contentShape modifier to it.
In the updated example below, all buttons (including the clear middle button) react to taps and the whole area is sensitive to drag gestures. The rectangles that were filled with solid color have been replaced with just a plain color (because it's simpler).
ZStack {
    Color.blue //simulates spriteKit view
        .ignoresSafeArea()

    HStack(spacing: 0) { //my buttons
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red.opacity(0.00001))
            .border(.red, width: 2)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("flip page left")
            }

        Color.clear
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) //  added
            .border(.green, width: 2)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("flip page right")
            }

        Button {
            print("button PRESSED")
        } label: {
            Color.black
                .border(.yellow, width: 2)
        }
    }
    .gesture( //  moved to button container
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                //simulates spriteKit drag handling,
                //for example animated page flipping
                print("DragGesture",value.velocity)
            }
    )
}


Thank you for your reply!
Unfortunately, the gesture HAS to be attached to blue rectangle, because it is just simulating a Combine approach to SKView gesture recognizer system.
